# Get value of paper-listbox from vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, polymer

Since MDL does not offer a select element I decided to use a paper-dropdown-menu in combination with a paper-listbox to get the desired result. Now if the user chooses an option and presses a button I would like to read the chosen value from vanilla JavaScript (jQuery is also possible).

To be more specific: If it was a normal textfield I'd do

```
var user_input = $('#text-input-field').val()
```

Is there something similar for Polymer elements?

If possible I would like to avoid writing my own webcomponent.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular problem that you are having as the standard DOM methods appear to work just fine?

```js
// Define the class for a new element called custom-element
class CustomElement extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() {
    return 'custom-element';
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.value = 'The value.';
    this.textContent = 'I\'m a custom-element.';
  }
}
// Register the new element with the browser
customElements.define(CustomElement.is, CustomElement);

const custom = document.querySelector('custom-element');
console.log(custom.value);
```

```html
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/polymer+2.0.0-rc.2/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<custom-element />
```

Comment: You're right it works I just tried to get the value from the wrong element. I have the following structure:

    <paper-dropdown-menu>
        <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
            <paper-item>Cat</paper-item>
            <paper-item>Dog</paper-item>
            <paper-item>Bird</paper-item>
        </paper-listbox>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>

I tried reading the value from the paper-listbox instead of the paper-dropdown-menu which works!